# Finding PDC from domain name in Linux (Linux equivalent of nltest /dcname:MYDOMAIN)

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I can find the PDC (Primary Domain Controller) from my Windows machine using the command `nltest /dcname:MYDOMAIN`.
I need to find the PCD from a Linux machine. Is there a way?
The only information that my script will have is the domain name and user name.

> *background of this (for the curious/completeness): I'm automating some password management procedures and so far I can deal with all the ftp, ssh and database passwords. Now I've managed to maintain the AD users as well, but I've had to supply the PDC's myself after looking them up from my windows machine - I'd like to supply just the domain and let my scripts do the rest, including the PDC lookup.*

The given answer by Lenniey is perfect and resolved my problem; just as a complete reference, I looked further into this and found the following sites that can be useful for others with similar needs:
[DNS Records that are required for proper functionality of Active Directory](https://servergeeks.wordpress.com/tag/_ldap-_tcp-pdc-_msdcs/)
[Find domain name with command line](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-domain-name-command-line/)

Comment: Why do you need the PDC for that? Isn't _any_ DC enough?

Comment: No, smbpasswd command requires the PDC because it's the only _write_ node, others are read-only. Is there even a way to find backup DCs? I could start there, if you know it...

Comment: This is wrong. There are RODCs, but not every DC is RODC. All ordinary DCs are read-write.

Comment: Ah, ok, I don't know much about this to be honest, I was essentially quoting the smbpasswd man page; anyhow, looking up the dns as recommended by @Lenniey worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.tld` and then use `awk` to format your output, e.g.:

`nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.tld | grep _ldap | awk '{print $7}'`

(it isn't pretty, but you can refine it to your use-case).

Comment: Awesome! It worked, thanks!  
For completeness; I had to use the windows command `wmic computersystem get domain` to get the actual domain address (everywhere else I looked was just getting the shortname which isn't good enough for the SRV entry).

Answer (score 0):

The `adcli` command will also provide this. (It's available in Ubuntu in the `adcli` package.)

Run

```bash
$ adcli info your.domain
```

and the output gives various details, including the domain controller.

You can get *just* the domain controller hostname, cutting out everything else with:

```bash
$ adcli info your.domain | grep -oP '^domain-controller = \K.*'
```